# How to perform this Terminal Trick? Can't even name it

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I don't even know what to call this...
When you open nethogs in terminal it opens up a window when you exit the whole terminal content are intact (certainly no screen clear was used). Need to what to call this and how to do this.
Thank you

[Before opening application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HeWb.png)

[Opened Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNRKb.png)

[Closed Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myh5p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all the trick is made by **[ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS)**

From nethogs README:

> Nethogs depends on ncurses for the text-based interface

Comment: Good sir, thank you for replying. If I may ask does vi (editor) also use ncurses?